# How to avoid rate limit when managing roles for multiple users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
 if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("Nice try, but you can't")
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have permissions.')
  const role = message.mentions.roles.first() 
    if (!role)  {
 return message.channel.send("Please mention a role");
    }else {
   await message.guild.members.fetch()
   const targets = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.roles.cache.has(role))


   targets.forEach(member => member.roles.remove(role))
message.channel.send(`Done!`)
}
```

Here's my code for mass roles removal. This is getting rate limited. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should never think of a way to override rate limits. If your code is being rate limited, it's done so for a very good reason for you to not abuse the Discord API. Unless there's really a way to lap around it in a way that doesn't harm the API and doesn't strictly override rate limits, you should never look at this option.

Comment: Yeah. I am not trying to over ride. But to do it in a way that, it doesn't harm the API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a role remove command without getting rate limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990669/how-to-make-a-role-remove-command-without-getting-rate-limited)

Comment: Yes. It does answer my question.