# How to make a role remove command without getting rate limited?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("Nice try, but you can't")
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have permissions.')
  const role = message.mentions.roles.first() 
    if (!role)  {
 return message.channel.send("Please mention a role");
    }else {
   await message.guild.members.fetch()
  const targets = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.roles.cache.has(role))


   await targets.forEach(member => member.roles.remove(role))
message.channel.send(`Done`)
}}};
```

This is a command for removing roles from all the server members. How can it be made such that it doesn't hit the rate limit?
Here are some solutions I tried which didn't work.

```
targets.forEach((member, i) => { setTimeout(() => { member.roles.remove(role)) }, i*1000); });
```

```
var index = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
   if (index < targets.length - 1)
      targets[index].roles.remove(role);
   else
     clearInterval(myInterval);

   index++;
}, 1000);
```

P•S When I run it on my small test server with 80 members it works. But in bigger servers it doesn't. That's because of rate limit (I think). How can I not hit the rate limit and get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your just fire off multiple asynchronous calls, that return an error if they run into an error.

Try to use a map instead, and you can await the array of promises that you'll get with Promise.all:

```
  await Promise.all(targets.map(async (member) => {
   await member.roles.remove(role)
  }));
```

> **Answer 2**

This Function allows us to do any API request and if it's being rate limited it will create a timeout with the time that request returned.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
function discordRetryHandler(input, init) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(input, init)
            .then(res => {
            if (res.headers.get('content-type') === 'application/json') {
                return res.json();
            }
            else {
                return { retry_after: undefined };
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
            if (typeof res.retry_after === 'number') {
                setTimeout(() => resolve(discordRetryHandler(input, init)), res.retry_after);
            }
            else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        })
            .catch(reject);
    });
}
```

How to use it? In the example below I will use a delete request [Remove Guild Member Role](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member-role).

```
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `${client.user.bot ? "Bot " : ""}${client.token}`
        }
    };
   await discordRetryHandler(`https://discord.com/api/v7/guilds/${guild?.id}/members/${member?.id}/roles/${role.id}`, requestOptions);
```

Comment: Won't this be rate limited?

Comment: As I remember probably no but it will notify me I will update my answer with another approach directly via api.

Comment: I tried it with the targets being all the server members. It got rate limited.Other approach?

Comment: ```Authorization: `${client.user?.bot ? "Bot " : ""}${client.token}`  ``` Unexpected token '.'

Comment: Remove the `?`(question mark) after the user

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Comment: Don't we need to multiply by `1000` in the timeout?

`setTimeout(() => resolve(discordRetryHandler(input, init)), res.retry_after * 1000);`

Comment: it returns in millis i think